# How to resolve this url rewrite issue?

Tags: c#, url-rewriting

I have following 2 rules

***rule 1:***

```
<rule name="DirectoryRewrite" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="(.*)/?$" />
    <conditions>
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
        <add input="{URL}" pattern="\.aspx" negate="true" />
        <add input="{URL}" pattern="\.ashx" negate="true" />
        <add input="{URL}" pattern="\.asmx" negate="true" />
        <add input="{URL}" pattern="\.axd$" negate="true" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Rewrite" url="/Views/{R:1}/default.aspx" />
</rule>
```

***rule 2:***

```
<rule name="RootRewrite" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="(.*)" />
    <conditions>
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
        <add input="{URL}" pattern="\.aspx" negate="true" />
        <add input="{URL}" pattern="\.ashx" negate="true" />
        <add input="{URL}" pattern="\.asmx" negate="true" />
        <add input="{URL}" pattern="\.axd$" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}.aspx" matchType="IsFile" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Rewrite" url="/Views/{R:1}.aspx" />
</rule>
```

I have a folder named `user` in my root directory which contains `settings.aspx` & `default.aspx`, and root also contains few files i.e. `faq.aspx &` `contact.aspx`.

This is what I am trying to achieve, if someone enters

> site.com/user

then take it to user directory by using rule 1, and in the same way if someone types

> site.com/terms

, it should take them to terms.aspx. By far rule one is working fine and it redirects to the given directory but when I am trying to get to the pages in root directory (i.e. `terms` or `contact`) it matches them to the rule 1 and tries to look for `terms` or `contact` directory and upon finding nothing it returns `The resource cannot be found.`

Can you please point me out what I am doing wrong.